# ffmpeg - How do I capture AND rotate a video at the same time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to record video from a USB camera using ffmpeg. The issue is that the camera is upside down and can't be repositioned, so I have to rotate 180°.

So far I'm using this command to capture:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -t 00:58:00 -i /dev/video0 output.mp4
```

And then I rotate it using this other command:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vf "rotate=180*(PI/180), format=yuv420p" -metadata:s:v rotat=0 -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy ROTATED_output.mp4;
```

Both commands are working perfeclty but it takes me twice the time. Is it possible to capture with the filter enabled so that the frames are rotated before being saved the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the filters from your second command to your first command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -t 00:58:00 -i /dev/video0 -vf "rotate=180*(PI/180),format=yuv420p" output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked like a charm!